# Why is getline() in C++ not working? (no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ofstream&, std::string&)'

Tags: c++, getline

I'm trying to read from a file, but C++ is not wanting to run `getline()`.

I get this error:

```
C:\main.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ofstream&, std::string&)'
          std::getline (file,line);
                                 ^
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string line;

    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("test.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
     {
       while ( file.good() )
       {
         getline (file,line);
         cout << line << endl;
       }
       file.close();
     }


}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::getline` is designed for use with input stream classes (`std::basic_istream`) so you should be using the `std::ifstream` class:

```
std::ifstream file("test.txt");
```

Moreover, using `while (file.good())` as a condition for input in a loop is generally bad practice. Try this instead:

```
while ( std::getline(file, line) )
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Now it works, except it doesn't print anything. "test.txt" is in the same directory as the cpp file

Comment: @Jamil Change `while ( file.good() )` to `while ( getline(file, line) )`

Comment: Apparently the while is still always false

Comment: @Jamil Does your file have anything in it? Check if your file successfully opened by adding an `else` statement to the initial `if` and print something out.

Comment: It turns out I had to specify the entire path to the file. Is there a way I can just write the file name? (I thought putting it in the same directory would work.)

Comment: It's implementation-defined whether the compiler will allow you to omitt the full path. I wouldn't know how to do otherwise without searching for the full path with the command line and accessing it with `argv`.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that's a different question.

Comment: @Jamil On Windows, to find "test.txt" without a path, it has to be in the current working directory, which depends primarily on how you call your executable, and in no way on where the .cpp file is.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads characters from an **input stream** and places them into a string. In your case your 1st argument to `getline` is of type [`ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream). You must use [ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)

```
std::ifstream file;
```