# Why is my program giving error (file handling)?

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

ofstream fileData;
ifstream writeData;

void newAccount();


int main()
{
    string data[10][3];
    int choice=0,i,j;


    fileData.open("D:\\Desktop\\input.txt");

    for(i=1; i<10&&(!fileData.eof());i++)
    {
        for(j=0; i<3;j++)
            getline(fileData,data[i][j]);
    }

    fileData.close();

    for(i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; i<3;j++)
            cout<<data[i][j];
    cout<<endl;
    }

    while(choice!=8)
    {

        cout<<"             Hi, Welcome to the Bank"
            <<"\n\n1.New Account.\n2.Deposit Money\n3.Withdraw Money\n4.Balance Enquiry"
            <<"\n5.Account Holder List\n6.Close An Account\n7.Modify An Account\n8.Exit\n\n";

        cin>>choice;

        if(choice==1)
        {
            newAccount();
        }

    }
```

its saying

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:38:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ofstream&, std::string&)’
             getline(fileData,data[i][j]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is getline() in C++ not working? (no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ofstream&, std::string&)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658837/why-is-getline-in-c-not-working-no-matching-function-for-call-to-getline)

Comment: I like how you added the gibberish at the end so you can avoid the "it looks like your post is mostly code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read from `std::ofstream` which is an output stream. Use `std::ifstream` or `std::fstream`.

Comment: now it's giving me another error... it seems to not be able to find the file... i am using an online compiler... can u recommend something about that??

Comment: For online compilers you may have to read the documentation to figure out if files are possible and how to create and use.

Comment: `D:\\Desktop\\input.txt` for an online compiler? Seems very strange for a path. I would expect most online compilers to be running as a linux container. Although even if this was a windows container  a `D:\\Desktop` folder would be strange as well.

Comment: i am new to programming, so I dont know much aout the details. What path should I use for the respective file? I am using GDB.

Comment: Try: `"input.txt"`  instead of `"D:\\Desktop\\input.txt"`however your application may need to create this file before you try to read it. That is unless the online compiler gives you access to some virtual filesystem (read the documentation about your online compiler first). And this assumes that the online compiler allows files at all. Allowing files may not be enabled because of the extra work + storage needs and security implications.